# Outline $M\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ with $z^2-5z\bar{z}+2\bar{z}^2+8=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to outline $M\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ with $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$

$M$ is specified by the condition $z^2-5z\bar{z}+2\bar{z}^2+8=0$

Plugging in $z=x+iy$, I find

$$-x^2-4y^2+xyi+4=0$$

Solving for $y$ leaves

$$y=\frac{xi}{8}\pm\sqrt{-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2-4}{4}}$$

$$y=\frac{xi}{8}\pm\sqrt{-\frac{x^2}{2}-1}$$

How does one continue from here? I think the solution will be, that $M$ contains just two or four elements of $\mathbb{C}$.

Kind regards
Philipp

Comment: Starting at "Solving for $y$ leaves", your solution becomes quite wrong. Before that, the identity $$-2x^2-7y^2+2xyi+8=0$$ is also wrong. Please redo the steps leading to it.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected it. How do I continue?

Comment: Actually, "plugging in $z=x+iy$", you should rather "find" $$-x^2-4y^2-xyi+4=0$$ but let us continue anyway. Asking that this is $0$ is asking that the real part and the imaginary part are both $0$ hence the condition is equivalent to $$-x^2-4y^2+4=0=xy$$ Can you finsh?

Comment: $x=\sqrt{4-4y^2}$ and $xy=0$ $$\Rightarrow \sqrt{4-4y^2}\cdot y=0$$ I am left with $$y^2=\left|y\right|$$ This equation only holds true for $y=1$ and $y=-1$. Why not for $y=0$ (Desmos only gave the other two answers), but I think $y=0$ musst be correct too? Plugging all $y$ into $$-x^2-4y^2+4=0$$ gives me $$x=\pm 2$$ and $$x=0$$

Comment: ?? Start with $xy=0$. Hence $x=0$ or $y=0$. If $x=0$, then $4y^2=x^2+4y^2=4$ hence... If $y=0$,  then $x^2=x^2+4y^2=4$ hence... End of the proof.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. That's a quicker way. But I found the right solution with my calculation too. $$z=\pm 2$$ and $$z=\pm 1i$$